# how to write not like queries in spark sql using scala api?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to convert the following query to Spark SQL using Scala API:

```sql
select ag.part_id name from sample c join testing ag on c.part=ag.part and concat(c.firstname,c.lastname) not like 'Dummy%'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this would work:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val c = sqlContext.table("sample")
val ag = sqlContext.table("testing")

val fullnameCol = concat(c("firstname"), c("lastname))

val resultDF = c.join(ag, (c("part") === ag("part")) && !fullnameCol.like("Dummy%"))
```

For more information about the functions I used above, please check the following links:

- [org.apache.spark.sql.functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$)
- [org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)
- [org.apache.spark.sql.Column](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

Comment: hi i am getting below error <console>:42: error: value like is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: @praveen can you share your code? maybe you are calling the `like` function on the wrong object

Comment: Hi thanks man i got the answer.  i made some mistake thank u :)

Comment: @praveen: Good to know you succeeded! If you don't mind, please consider marking the answer as correct if it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You mean this

```
df.filter("filed1 not like 'Dummy%'").show
```

or

```
df.filter("filed1 ! like 'Dummy%'").show
```

Answer (score -1):

use like this

df.filter(!'col1.like("%COND%").show